# Как редактировать код в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день. Возможно ли редактировать код сайта через админку wordpress(не добавлять новую статью, а, например, изменить дизайн сайта)? Если да, то как?

Comment: Внешний вид -> Редактор

Comment: Кое-что можно, но это почти гарантированный способ уронить насмерть сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Если Вы хотите отредактировать шаблон то зайдите 
Админ панель-> Внешний вид ->Редактор
По умолчанию он сразу откроет style.css 
Если Вы хотите отредактировать Плагин
Админ панель-> Плагины ->Редактор